# Java Spring end URL with a file extension

Tags: java, spring

I have a service that returns a string. String is in the form of XML. The URL is /monitoring. But the client now wants, that the URL ends with /status.xml. How do I do that? I tried to change the value in the GetMapping, but then it stopped working. Is there anything special in URL ending with status.xml and how can I achieve this?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/monitoring")
public ResponseEntity getStatuses() throws TransformerException, UnsupportedEncodingException, JAXBException {
    return indexService.getStatusEntity();
}

public ResponseEntity getStatusEntity() throws JAXBException, UnsupportedEncodingException, TransformerException {
        byte[] xml = getStatus();
        String xmlStr = new String(xml, "UTF-8");
        xmlStr = xmlStr.replaceAll("<", "<");
        xmlStr = xmlStr.replaceAll(">", ">");
        Source src = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStr.getBytes("UTF-8")));

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);
        transformer.transform(src, result);

        return setDocumentHeaderAndReturnOK(bos.toByteArray());
    }

private byte[] getStatus() throws JAXBException {
    String tomcat = ServerInfo.getServerInfo();
    String[] pieces = tomcat.split("/");
    App status = new App(applicationInfoService.getVersion().getBody(), "name", "OK", "",
        new ServerPlatform(pieces[1], pieces[0]), new RunTimeEnvironment(System.getProperty("java.version"), "JAVA"),
        checkExternalDependencies());

    QName main = new QName("app");
    JAXBElement<App> root = new JAXBElement<>(main, App.class, status);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(App.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root, out);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root, System.out);

    return out.toByteArray();
}

    @Transactional
public ResponseEntity setDocumentHeaderAndReturnOK(byte[] contents) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    String fileType = "xml";

    String filename = "status.xml";
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/" + fileType));

    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + filename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    return new ResponseEntity(contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

EDIT:

I tried generating the classes with jaxb and the use those to make the XML. But that does not change the url. I have the XML content generated correctly, i just need a way to get the GetMapping from /monitoring to /status.xml. What does it even mean to have a url in the form of status.xml ?

Comment: Hi @Marko, would you add your code?

Comment: @Reg i added the code.

Comment: Do you have any resource mappers?

Comment: For swagger. Cant seem to find anything else.

Comment: @Reg what exactly do you mean under resource mappers?